# mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] 1146: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist WTF?

Tags: mysql

Ive just unstalled 5.7 MySQL under Windows. I cant use it, I tried to run the "mysql_upgrade": and it dies: [ERROR] 1146: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist

plugin.frm and plugin.idb exists....

Comment: a reinstall solved it. Never operate on these files directly.